# V-meter's value is stabilizing when measuring

Tags: multimeter, semiconductors, power-measurement

I am curious about my V-meter behaviour. Sometimes when I measure voltage the voltage showed by V-meter is slowly dropping until it stabilizes after few seconds. And same for current, except current is slowly rising. But not always, just sometimes. I heard that when measuring bias conditions of MOSFETs with V-meter (gate voltage is a good example, or the voltage divider in front of it) has similar effects on V-meter, when voltage is measured.

I think there is nothing wrong with my multimeter since this effect occurs occasionally.

Questions:

- Do these effects occur in V/A-meter due to high resistance of the circuit to be measured?
- Should I wait until the value stabilizes and then take notes (for calculation, circuit understanding, etc.)?

Comment: The MOSFET may be heating, and changing the transconductance, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A meter by itself shouldn't behave as you describe.  However, the circuit it is measuring can certainly have such behavior.